# opengles 3D graphics raspberry pi

Tags: c++, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, geany

I can't find a tutorial for the use of **OpenGLES** **3D** graphics in c++, on a raspberry pi so I can program a video game with **c++**, also, I cannot find a **raspberry pi** compatible **OpenGLES** library.

***Edit***:

At the time, I just couldn't find a library for working with **OpenGL** / **OpenGLES**, such as **GLFW**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google for Broadcom OpenGL ES and start here

http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs